# wkhtmltopdf "file output vs stdout" on ubuntu with x server (xvfb-run)

Tags: ubuntu, wkhtmltopdf, xvfb, xserver

This doesn't work

```
echo '<p>Hello</p>' | /usr/bin/xvfb-run -a /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf - - > ~/notworking.pdf
```

But this works:

```
echo '<p>Hello</p>' | /usr/bin/xvfb-run -a /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf - ~/working.pdf
```

**Please notice how the files are being created above**

Files Attached (Google Drive Links):

- [working.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bys6bZ3t66mCWFZJZFZDYkJFWkk/view?usp=sharing). Raw Data: http://pastebin.com/yNqBLRpz
- [notworking.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bys6bZ3t66mCbUx5MFVGUExiaHM/view?usp=sharing). Raw Data: http://pastebin.com/aRv9yfmF

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 (64Bit)

No errors in both commands, files are generated properly with file size:

```
ubuntu@ip-*-*-*-*:~$ du -s -B1 ~/working.pdf
8192    /home/ubuntu/working.pdf
ubuntu@ip-*-*-*-*:~$ du -s -B1 ~/notworking.pdf
8192    /home/ubuntu/notworking.pdf
```

On windows, it is working as expected.

There are minor changes in Raw Data, which I am not able to understand.

Has anyone faced similar issue ? Can anyone point me to link to the solution, i couldn't find here on SO or the net.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
echo '<p>Hello</p>' | /usr/bin/xvfb-run -a /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf -q - - > ~/notworking.pdf
```

executing wkhtmltopdf in quiet mode (`-q`) fixed the issue. As even the following was prepended in the pdf file:

```
Loading page (1/2)
Printing pages (2/2)
Done
```

Comment: FYI: Seems this was fixed in newer versions https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1915 https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1980